# C++ Array comparison and printing difference

Tags: c++, arrays

The thing i want to do is compare two arrays, A and B, and post numbers from array B that doesn't appear in array A.

http://pastebin.com/u44DKsWf  My full code.

Problem starts at line 42 i think.

```
int writingPosition = 1;
for (int c = 1; c<=firstArrayLength; c++)
{
    for(int z = 1; z>secondArrayLength; z++)
    {
        if (firstArray[c] != secondArray[z])
        {
            thirdArray[writingPosition] = secondArray[z];
            writingPosition++;
        }
        if (firstArray[c] == secondArray[z])
        {
            thirdArray[c] == '0'; // NEED FIXING I GUESS
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that i mark numbers that dont fit my task as '0', so later on i can print array while ignoring 0.

Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention, that it gives me 2 numbers  that fits my task. First one and the last one. It overrides all others.

Comment: ^^add this to your post as an edit

Comment: inner loop `for(int z = 1; z>secondArrayLength; z++)`: breaking condition should probably be `z<` or `z<=` instead? also do you start your indices on `1` by design?

Comment: Just a suggestion also, maybe use a boolean type for your `thirdArray` as `true` and `false` are more readable than 0 and 1... still working on an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction to your code should be somewhat like :

```
int writingPosition = 1;
for (int c = 1; c<=firstArrayLength; c++)
 {
  for(int z = 1; z<=secondArrayLength; z++)
   {
    if (firstArray[c] != secondArray[z])
     {
       thirdArray[writingPosition] = secondArray[z];
       writingPosition++;
     }
     if (firstArray[c] == secondArray[z])
        continue;
   }
 }
```

> On a side note : Prefer using `0` as the base index for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`binary_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) from [`algorithm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) module from C++ Standard Library.
Note this works with `std::vector` aswell.

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/7lPyQ9)

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> firstArray { 1, 3, 5 }; // stack based array like int[3]
    std::array<int, 3> secondArray { 2, 3, 4 };

    // Sort first array to be able to perform binary_search on it
    std::sort(firstArray.begin(), firstArray.end());

    for (const auto secondArrayItem : secondArray)
    {
        // Binary search is a very efficient way of searching an element in a sorted container of values
        if (std::binary_search(firstArray.begin(), firstArray.end(), secondArrayItem) == false)
        {
            std::cout << "Item " << secondArrayItem << " does not exist in firstArray" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code.

Arrays of size `s` always range from 0 to `s-1`, so in your case you should use

```
for(int g = 0; g<50; g++)
```

i.s.o.

```
for(int g = 0; g<=50; g++)
```

and similar for the other arrays

Secondly, you fill the third array with `char` elements, and then compare them to `int`

```
thirdArray[c] == '0';
```

and later

```
if(thirdArray[g] != 0)
```

Either use `'0'` or `0` both times, but don't mix them up.

But the general algorithm doesn't make much sense either, you're overriding third array both based on index `c` as index `z`. 
Also the range on `z` makes little sense.

(I assume this is homework or at least you're trying to study, so won't simply give a solution)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you store the numbers that doesn't exist in a string and then you print the string from cout? this is how you can do this:

```
string output = "";
bool isFound = false;
for (int c = 1; c<=secondArrayLength; c++)
{
    isFound = false;
    for(int z = 1; z>firstArrayLength; z++)
    {
        if (secondArray[c] == firstArray[z])
        {
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
    if(!isFound)
          output+=(secondArray[c].str()+" ");
}
cout<<output;
```

try this it must work fine